# Is there any method to check a single or multiple row in jqgrid and retrieve onl that data from the jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

i have a jqgrid with some data.I want a column that just have check boxes that will select the whole row or multiple row and display its content on a button click.is ther any grid property to do so? also when i retrieve data from the jqgrid using getRowData ,i am geting the data with the "input" tags as the rows are editable.Is ther a way to just retrieve the plain data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up the grid, make sure you specify

```
multiselect: true
```

This will allow multiple rows to be selected. In another function called when a button is hit, you can retrieve the selected rows by

```
var rowIDs = $(jqgridTable).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrow');
```

Then get the row data for each row like this:

```
var currentRowData;
for(var i=0; i<rowIDs.length; i++){
    currentRowData = $(jqgridTable).jqGrid('getRowData', rowIDs[i]);
    alert(currentRowData["columnName"]);
    ...
}
```